# bsDatepicker not work with Angular form Validation

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datepicker, angular-validation

I use the bootstrap datepicker with in my Angular application. I want to add a validation to verify that the date is correct(not "Invalid Date"), but when I have added the `formControlName="birthDate"` for this control, the calendar didn't work correctly, the days are duplicated on the small popup window, can you tell me how the resolve this problem, please?

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="birthDate" name="birthDate"
         formControlName="birthDate"
         bsDatepicker
         [bsConfig]="{dateInputFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY'}"
         [(ngModel)]="response.date"
         [disabled]="IsNotModifiable()">
</div>
```

I have tried to add a attribut `(input)=verify()` who check the date, but it's never triggered.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
   <input [(ngModel)]="Date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" class="form-control" formControlName="Date" #dateneeded ="bsDatepicker" bsDatepicker [bsConfig]="datepickerConfig">
       <div class="input-group-append">
           <span class="input-group-text" (click)="dateneeded.show()">
           <i class="far fa-calendar-plus" value="open"></i>
           </span>
        </div>
   </div>
```

this piece of code is working for me. Make sure you have imported bsdatepicker module in appmodule.ts

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work, when i place the mouse on the popup calendar, i will have many times 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4... i don't know why, but i think it's related to the binding (formControlName="")

Comment: Sorry, i have no idea to create a demo